# remove and add class to localStorage

Tags: javascript

When i click on a link it has class `nav_sidebar_link_active`, but if i refresh(f5) this page, this class is disappearing and it's a problem, need add/remove it to/from localStorage, so there are when js code was commented i did tried compare `linkId !== link` and if true, need to remove this class from localStorage, and below add to localStorage

```js
const box = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_sidebar_link');

/*for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].onclick = function(e) {
        const target = e.target;
        const linkId = '#' + target.id + '-anchor';
        const link = target.getAttribute('href')
        for (let j = 0; j < box.length; j++) {
            if (linkId !== link) {
                // maybe here remove from localStorage
                box[j].classList.remove('nav_sidebar_link_active');
            }
        }
        // maybe here add to localStorage
        this.classList.add('boxActive');
    }
}*/

for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].onclick = function() {
        for (let j = 0; j < box.length; j++) {
            box[j].classList.remove('nav_sidebar_link_active');
        }
        this.classList.add('nav_sidebar_link_active');
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.nav_sidebar_wrap {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 29.2rem;
}
.nav_sidebar_wrap.contacts-mod {
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav_sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 34%;
  left: 10rem;
  max-width: 28rem;
  z-index: 999;
}

.nav_sidebar_item {
  padding: 0 0 2rem 0;
}

.nav_sidebar_link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav_sidebar_link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.nav_sidebar_link:hover:before {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.nav_sidebar_link:active:before {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.nav_sidebar_link_active:before {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav_sidebar who-mod">
              <li class="nav_sidebar_item"><a id="newhomes" href="#newhomes-anchor" class="nav_sidebar_link">new homes</a></li>
              <li class="nav_sidebar_item"><a id="investments" href="#investments-anchor" class="nav_sidebar_link">investments</a></li>
              <li class="nav_sidebar_item"><a href="#acquisitions-anchor" id="acquisitions" class="nav_sidebar_link">Acquisitions
                  and Disposals</a></li>
              <li class="nav_sidebar_item"><a href="#lettings-anchor" id="lettings" class="nav_sidebar_link">Lettings
                  and management</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: You basically want to save the state of active link right ?

Comment: @jashgopani yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the id of the active item in `localStorage` each time it changes. Then, on page load, retrieve this id, and give this element the active class.

```
const box = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_sidebar_link');

let prevActive = localStorage.getItem('activeId');
if(prevActive) document.getElementById(prevActive).classList.add('nav_sidebar_link_active')

for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].onclick = function() {
        for (let j = 0; j < box.length; j++) {
            box[j].classList.remove('nav_sidebar_link_active');
        }
        this.classList.add('nav_sidebar_link_active');
        localStorage.setItem('activeId', this.id);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/d2tkrx5n/show)

Answer (score 0):

Get the `active-link` from local Storage on page load.

Then forEach box what you were doing was correct. Whenever any one of the boxes is clicked remove the class from rest of the boxes, and then add the class to the currently clicked box. And finally set the item in localStorage using `localStorage.setItem`

I have just replaced the classic for loop syntax with functional looping syntax.

```js
const activeClass = "nav_sidebar_link_active";
const inactiveClass = ".nav_sidebar_link";
const storageKey = "active-link";

const activeLink = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
if (activeLink) {
  //add active class if the value retrieved from localStorage is not null
  document.querySelector(`#${activeLink}`).classList.toggle(activeClass);
}


const box = document.querySelectorAll(inactiveClass);
box.forEach((b) => {
  //add event listener to each box
  b.onclick = (e) => {
    //remove active class from all boxes except this one
    box.forEach((boxItem) => {
      if (boxItem.id != b.id) {
        boxItem.classList.remove(activeClass);
      }
    });
    //set the class of current box and store it in localStorage
    e.target.classList.toggle(activeClass);
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, e.target.id);
  };
});
```